# Cluster integrity has been disturbed

Tags: aerospike

I get this error on only one node on a 2-node cluster once every week. 
Here's the errors I got on the AMC:

Main error:

> Cluster integrity has been disturbed

Error for every set :

> Mismatch in replication factor for namespace test as shown by nodes

For information, the 2 nodes have **the same aerospike.conf file** with a replication factor of 2. 
Another thing that caught my attention is that, the whole cluster is not available while only one node is down (not visible), so I am questionning myself on the HA of Aerospike.

To solve this problem, I simply restart the node not visible.

[On the aerospike documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/troubleshoot/cluster/#cluster-size-change) it says :

> This can be true if a set of nodes has split from the main cluster. (This is sometimes referred to as a split brain.) Generally, it is easiest to restart the “lost” node(s) to get it/them to rejoin the cluster.

But as this problem occurs every week, I would love to solve this once and for all :)

Comment: can you grep the log for 'cluster integrity' (case insensitive) and share if there are any faults please.  Version would also be helpful

Comment: I sense a disturbance in the force.

Comment: @BenBates 

Logs: 
 `CLUSTER INTEGRITY FAULT. [Phase 1 of 2] To fix, issue this command across all nodes:  dun:nodes=bb9648009565000,bb9017602565000`


Version : Community Edition 3.7.0.1

Tell me if you need more

Comment: This is only the error message, I would need maybe 1000 lines previous to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One suggestion is to set paxos-recovery-policy to auto-reset-master and the cluster should form back together on it's own assuming the cause of the issue is a temporary network flux meaning the cluster might lose integrity.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I updated this configuration and I will keep you update.

Comment: 10 days after this, no cluster integrity problem detected.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I work for Aerospike, after doing some research "Mismatch in replication factor for namespace test as shown by nodes" could be linked to the node not being visible.  In a 2 node cluster with replication factor 2, when one node is unavailable, replication factor will drop to 1 to maintain data availability. When the node re-joins the cluster the replication factors, for a short while, will not match,  AMC will retry and you should not see repetition of this error.

We would need to get to the bottom of the node going down issue to answer your second question, see my comment.